# Angular 9 build error Custom named exports

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have a project with `Angular 9.0`.

I create new library with this command:

`ng g library @scope/xxx --skip-install`.

when I exec command `ng b @scope/xxx` to for build, I encountred with this error:

```
[error] Error: Custom named exports were specified for E:\...\dist\scope\xxx\fesm5\scope-xxx.js but it does not appear to be a CommonJS module
```

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was weird But this solution is useful.

I add the `"module": "es2015"` to `tsconfig.lib.json` file library, section `compilerOptions`.

and error fixed.